# solving in x involving both exponential and logarithmic function

Tags: logarithms, exponentiation

Is it possible to solve a function with both exponential and logarithm such as
$a x^2−b.\log(x)= c$
in closed form; where $a,b,c$ are constants and $a>0$ and $b>0$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First it should be said that $x^2$ is not exponential, since $x$ is your independent variable. An exponential terms generally means something of the form $e^{kx}$. Your equation is [transcendental](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transcendental_equation) and often does not have a solution in algebraic numbers (unlike quadratic eqations, for instance).

Comment: An exponential function is a function for which the variable is an exponent. For example $x \mapsto 2^x$ is an exponential function, as is $x \mapsto 7^{2x^3+4}$. Of course $2^x \equiv \operatorname{e}^{kx}$ when $k = \ln 2$.

Answer (score 3):

It depends what you mean by "solve". In general, not using [elementary functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_function), no. The general solution to the problem you posted above involves [Lambert's $W$-function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function).